# Where can I find the stock audio files (notifications, ringtones, etc) from iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a prototype/demo of an application and it is necessary for me to play back the iOS 6 audio files on a PC. Supposing I was able to access the file system on my iOS device, what path would I find those files under?

Comment: Nope. You may just as well close this, because to access them, you'll need to crack Apple's firmware, which isn't allowed. Not that the key is publicly available, but still, it's a legal issue, as is distributing the files if you have somehow managed to crack it.

Comment: Distributing files from the device is certainly out of bounds for this site, but where to find files on a device you own falls within the acceptable boundaries for questions on this site. Jailbreaking is on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is jailbroken, you can grab them from /System/Library/Audio/UISounds

Comment: Luckily it's super easy to jailbreak at the moment with the recent release of the evasi0n jailbreak tool.